# Apply comma to numbers in td of table

Tags: php, mysql, numbers

I have a list of numbers in a table resulting from mySQL:

How do I apply the comma to the number fields:  "min" and "max"

```
$query = "SELECT min, max, qty FROM cartons_current LIMIT 0,50";
$result = $db->query($query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
$o = '<table><thead><tr><th>Min</th><th>Max</th><th>Qty</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
while(list($min, $max, $qty) = $result->fetch_row()) {

$o .= '<tr><td>'.$min.'</td><td>'.$max.'</td><td>'.$qty.'</td></tr>';}
$o .= '</tbody></table>';
echo $o;
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "apply the comma"?  String concatenation?

Comment: number_format() or money_format() i think is what you are asking

Comment: Yes... my numbers are showing like "20000".  I would like them to appear "20,000"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `number_format()`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Wow. +1 for inferring the OP's needs.